# trying to run javascript program inside java generates EvaluatorException: Constructor for "ReferenceError" not found

Tags: java, rhino

I am trying to import `env.js` inside a java program

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main;

public class ScriptRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        Context cx = ContextFactory.getGlobal().enterContext();
        Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
        cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
        cx.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_7);
        Main.processSource(cx, "C:\\Java\\rhino1_7R4\\rhino1_7R4\\env.rhino.1.0.js");\\ <== this generates exception
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```

this is generating

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Constructor for "ReferenceError" not found. (C:\Java\rhino1_7R4\rhino1_7R4\env.rhino.1.0.js#75)
at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:913)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:969)
```

line 75 in env.rhino.1.0.js is

```
try { dontCare = globalize; }
```

the code block it is in is

```
var countOfMissing = 0, dontCare;
try { dontCare = globalize; }
catch (ex){ globalize = function(){ return {}; };
            countOfMissing++; }
```

I think this piece of javascript is fine. What it is failing on is trying to create the `ReferenceError` and failing there. My assumption was this is supposed to be part of the javascript engine.

has anyone come across this?

jdk is 1.7.0_45